# Capture click of Pay Now button in Paypal iFrame (cross domain)

Tags: jquery, iframe, paypal

I have a payment system using Paypal's payflow where they send me an iFrame to render.  I would like to capture when the "Pay Now" button has been clicked so I can hide a "Cancel" button on my page while the transaction is processing.

I have tried the usual jQuery:

`$("#iFrame .button").click(function(){});`

and

`$("#iFrame").contents().find("input[type='button']")`

but nothing is working.  I get the error:

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a cross-origin frame

Any ideas on how I can capture the click?

Comment: You can't do that. Imagine instead if you wanted to use javascript to click the Pay Now button on behalf of the user...

Comment: or capture keypresses in the username/password field...

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I've been using @JCue's answer for capturing the PayPal button click until I was on the deprecated Checkout.JS PayPal version.
Now we are migrating to the latest SDK version and it provides the `onClick` function out of the box.

```
<script>
 paypal.Buttons({
  // onClick is called when the button is clicked
  onClick: function(data, actions) {
   Your Code Here
  }
  ...
 })
</script>
```

Refer here - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/validation/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access any events or interact with an iFrame's content from the hosting site.

You can, however, tell if the user clicked inside of the iFrame. So, the best you could do is set a listener for the click into the iFrame and then assume that they are going forward with the order and hide your button on that. Like this:

```
focus();
var listener = addEventListener('blur', function() {
    if(document.activeElement === document.getElementById('iframe')) {
        // clicked
    }
    removeEventListener(listener);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

PayPal doesn't propagate its clicks so listen to the element added when the PayPal button is clicked.If you want to do something when PayPal Pay now button is clicked,
The best work around is this :

NOTE: 'paypal-checkout-sandbox' class is also the classname used by paypal even in production.
JQUERY :

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    if($(e.target).hasClass('paypal-checkout-sandbox')){
        //DO SOMETHING.
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  It's been 4 years already since I asked this.  My fix was to...was to...almost got it...I can't remember, but I will look it up when I get a chance to solve the mystery.

Comment: This goes well with the production version if anyone is wondering.